# Why does TMutex method Acquire() not lock a mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, c++builder

So far I have this code:

```
****SimpleForm.h****
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TMemo *Memo1;
    TButton *Button1;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
    TMutex *mtx;
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};

****SimpleForm.cpp****
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    mtx = new TMutex(true);
    WorkerThread *wt = new WorkerThread(false, mtx);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    mtx->Acquire();
        Memo1->Lines->Add("Locked...");
    mtx->Release();
}

****WorkerThread.h****
class WorkerThread : public TThread
{
private:
    TMutex *mtx;
protected:
    void __fastcall Execute();
public:
    __fastcall WorkerThread(bool CreateSuspended, TMutex *mtx);
    void __fastcall CheckLock();
};
****WorkerThread.cpp****
__fastcall WorkerThread::WorkerThread(bool CreateSuspended, TMutex *mtx)
    : TThread(CreateSuspended)
{
    this->mtx = mtx;
}

void __fastcall WorkerThread::Execute()
{
    while(true){
        Sleep(1000);
        Synchronize(CheckLock);
    }

}

void __fastcall WorkerThread::CheckLock(){
    this->mtx->Acquire();
    Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Locked from thread");
    //this->mtx->Release();
}
```

The problem is, `mtx->Acquire()` does not lock a mutex, when I comment the `mtx->Release()`, nothing changes during runtime, both threads can access the same shared resource at the same time, witch is not what I want. I was using p_threads in Linux environment, and when the mutex is locked, other threads waits for it to become available. How can I achieve the same result using C++ CodeGear 2009 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something else is the explanation to your problem because `TMutex::Acquire` does indeed acquire a lock on the mutex object. The implementation of `TMutex` looks like this:

```
procedure TMutex.Acquire;
begin
  if WaitFor(INFINITE) = wrError then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;

procedure TMutex.Release;
begin
  if not ReleaseMutex(FHandle) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

And `WaitFor` calls `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` passing the mutex handle.

Most likely is that you actually have more than one mutex somehow but I can't tell for sure since I can't see all of your code.

Finally, for within process synchronisation you should prefer the Windows critical section which performs better than the Windows mutex object. That is `TCriticalSection` in the RTL.

---

Following your update it is easy to see what is happening. All use of the lock happens in the main thread. You call `Synchronize` which results in the method executing on the main thread. If you call `CheckLock` directly from your `Execute` method then you will deadlock as intended.

You need to use `Synchronize` for all GUI calls. It works, broadly, by signaling the main thread that there is something in the synchronize queue and then waiting until the main thread has completed the work. It is an asynchronous method.

Comment: Just tested it with TCriticalSection, same results. I checked and the TMutext / TCriticalSection objects are the same in both threads, but somehow I can't get them to lock.

Comment: They do lock. I use these objects day in and day out. There's something else that I can't see.

Comment: I edited my initial code snippet. Now the full code is there. Notice the commented mtx->Release(); line, why the main thread can still successfully lock the mutex ?

Comment: See my update. I've worked it out now. Needed the extra code!

Comment: It works because the mutex is initially locked by the main thread, and then the worker thread synchronizes its UI updates to the main thread, so the main thread simply re-enters the lock is already has.  Since you are using `Sychoronize()`, just get rid of the mutex, as it is completely useless in your example.